# Python-Eve query filter to find records in a range of values

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, filtering, eve

I am using Python-Eve for my API (PostgresQL is my DB)

right now i am able to do `>` OR `<` operations individually as below

```
example.com/api?max_results=15&sort=-_id&where={"_id":">50"}
```

How can i query for `_ids` between two values like `_id>50` and `_id<100` ?

Comment: mongo like query operators `$gt` `$lt` are not working here

Comment: Mongo operators probably don't work on SQLAlchemy extension. Did you check the [Eve-SQLAlchemy docs](https://eve-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#using-flask-sqlalchemy)?

Comment: Yes, went through that but no where i can find help. I doubt if it is possible or not with Eve-SQLAlchemy, but it is a primary need for filtering data. Actually i query on date timestamp ranges

Comment: Can you open an issue on eve-sqlalchemy github page ? I too need exact same functionality (filter within date range)

Comment: Opened issue 18days ago, still no response
https://github.com/RedTurtle/eve-sqlalchemy/issues/114